# sort not sorting as expected (space and locale)

Tags: linux, sorting

I want to sort a text file through linux `sort`, that looks like this

```
v 1006
v10 1
v 1011
```

I would expect result like this:

```
v 1006
v 1011
v10 1
```

However, using `sort`, even with all kinds of options, the `v10 1` line is still in the middle. Why? I would understand `v10 1` being either on top on on the bottom (depending if space character is smaller or bigger than `1`), but for what reason it is kept in the middle?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It uses the system locale to determine the sorting order of letters. My guess is that with your locale, it ignores whitespace.

```
$ cat foo.txt 
v 1006
v10 1
v 1011
$ LC_ALL=C sort foo.txt
v 1006
v 1011
v10 1
$ LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 sort foo.txt
v 1006
v10 1
v 1011
```

Comment: just a small comment, you don't need to put the `;` in `LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 ; sort foo.txt`. There is a difference in behavior though. If you execute `SOME_VAR=foo some_command parameters` you are executing some_command with its parameters, and with the env var SOME_VAR being equal to foo, but just for this command. If after returning to the shell you `echo $SOME_VAR`, it will have the original value, not `foo`

Comment: Oh. OK, I get it now. But.... what is the POINT in ignoring the whitespaces at all?

Comment: Why does -k seem to respect whitespace in LC_ALL=en_US.utf8?

e.g.
LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 sort -k1,1 foo.txt gives the same behavior as LC_ALL=C sort foo.txt

Answer (score 4):

Your locale influences how the lines are sorted. For example I get this with my current locale:

```
% echo -e "v 1006\nv10 1\nv 1011" | sort
v 1006
v10 1
v 1011
```

But with C locale I get this:

```
% echo -e "v 1006\nv10 1\nv 1011" | LC_ALL=C sort
v 1006
v 1011
v10 1
```

I'm not sure why it behaves that way really. `LC_ALL=C` is pretty much equivalent to turning off all unexpected processing and going back to the byte-level operations (yeah - I'm skipping the details).

Why do different locale settings skip space is harder to explain though. If anyone can explain that would be good :)