# Need to sort IPs in Apache log file

Tags: bash, apache, shell

I have the Apache access logs. I want a list of IPs sorted by number of accesses they have made (count) but not the count number. Just the IP addresses sorted by access counts.

I have this command I've found here:

```
cat access_log | awk '{print $1}' | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -200 > output.txt
```

This gives an output like:

> 10000 66.249.79.18

`10000` is the count number. I need the IP only not the count. What is the modified command then?

Comment: Do you mind sharing some of the apache access_log output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort unique IP address in from Apache log](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18682308/608639), [Sorting IP address according to the second field in file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/71704/56041), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `-c` for the `uniq` command. This will eliminate the first column which is the count.

Full command

```
cat access_log | awk '{print $1}' | sort -n | uniq | sort -nr | head -200
```

Comment: Thanks the next question is I have a list now, of unique ip addresses. How do I resolve these to hostnames? Is there any script you can share here? thanks!

Comment: @sd100 that's a separate question but I'd use `nmblookup` or `nslookup`. See [this page for more details](https://serverfault.com/a/88129).