# can't explain sort(1) behaviour

Tags: linux, sorting, ls

I've been puzzled with this when I saw the following files listed by `ls` in strange order:

```
Star Wars Episode II - Attack of the Clones (2002) BDRip.mkv
Star Wars Episode III - Revenge of the Sith (2005) BDRip.mkv
Star Wars Episode I - The Phantom Menace (1999) BDRip.mkv
Star Wars Episode IV - A New Hope (1977) BDRip.mkv
Star Wars Episode VI - Return of the Jedi (1983) BDRip.mkv
Star Wars Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back (1980) BDRip.mkv
```

From human perspective 'I' should go first, then 'II' and so on.

so I created file with the following content:

```
$ cat 1
Star Wars Episode II - Attack
Star Wars Episode III - Revenge
Star Wars Episode I - The
Star Wars Episode IV - A
Star Wars Episode VI - Return
Star Wars Episode V - The
```

if I sort it it gives me this:

```
$ sort 1
Star Wars Episode II - Attack
Star Wars Episode III - Revenge
Star Wars Episode I - The
Star Wars Episode IV - A
Star Wars Episode VI - Return
Star Wars Episode V - The
```

However, if I remove '-' and everything after it sorts correct:

```
$ cat 1
Star Wars Episode II 
Star Wars Episode III 
Star Wars Episode I 
Star Wars Episode IV 
Star Wars Episode VI 
Star Wars Episode V 

$ sort 1
Star Wars Episode I 
Star Wars Episode II 
Star Wars Episode III 
Star Wars Episode IV 
Star Wars Episode V 
Star Wars Episode VI
```

So, as soon as I add any symbol after space it starts sorting unpredictable for me:

```
$ cat 1
Star Wars Episode II y
Star Wars Episode III x
Star Wars Episode I z
Star Wars Episode IV w
Star Wars Episode VI v
Star Wars Episode V u

$ sort 1
Star Wars Episode III x
Star Wars Episode II y
Star Wars Episode IV w
Star Wars Episode I z
Star Wars Episode VI v
Star Wars Episode V u
```

Any hint on this sort behaviour ?

**Update:**  sort: using ‘en_CA.UTF-8’ sorting rules

**update #2** as per comment below it is because of locale.

```
ls | LANG=C sort
Star Wars Episode I - The Phantom Menace (1999) BDRip.mkv
Star Wars Episode II - Attack of the Clones (2002) BDRip.mkv
Star Wars Episode III - Revenge of the Sith (2005) BDRip.mkv
Star Wars Episode IV - A New Hope (1977) BDRip.mkv
Star Wars Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back (1980) BDRip.mkv
Star Wars Episode VI - Return of the Jedi (1983) BDRip.mkv
```

Why then UTF8 locale makes it different ?
I checked with ru_RU.UTF8 (incorrect sorting) and ru_RU.KOI8-R (proper sorting)

**Update #3** It is about locale: http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/faq/#Sort-does-not-sort-in-normal-order_0021

Comment: Prepending `LC_ALL=C` makes it work so it must have something to do with the locale.

Comment: http://www.unix.com/showthread.php?t=156805 scripts for sorting files with roman numerals

Comment: Is "ii" a digraph in the ru_RU locale that sorts before "i" (when it's not being considerd a Roman numeral)? A quick Google shows that there have been bugs reported against the ru_RU.UTF8 locale for collation order issues, so it's entirely possible that's part of what you're seeing...

Comment: Please, look at my answer below and update to the original question. It is default behaviour of UTF8 locales, at least those I worked with. They ignore whitespaces. My original issue was not related to ru.RU.* locale, but *.UTF8 in general and en_CA.UTF8 in particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the proper explanation of this:

[Gnu coreutils FAQ: Sort does not sort in normal order](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/faq/#Sort-does-not-sort-in-normal-order_0021)

Found it on: [sort not sorting as expected (space and locale)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909404/sort-not-sorting-as-expected-space-and-locale)

Answer (score 1):

It ignores all non-alphanumeric characters when using a locale based sort:

```
II - Attack   -> "IIA"
III - Revenge -> "III"
I - The       -> "ITh"
IV - A        -> "IVA"
VI - Return   -> "VIR"
V - The       -> "VTh"
```

With `LC_ALL=C`, the space character is sorted in front of alphanumerics:

```
I - The       -> "I -"
II - Attack   -> "II "
III - Revenge -> "III"
IV - A        -> "IV "
V - The       -> "V -"
VI - Return   -> "VI "
```

So it is coincidence that this works, but it takes 30 more movies for it to actually fail.

Comment: Yes, thank you. correction: it is only UTF8 locales, as far as I see.