# "sort -s" thinks "p" comes before "d"?

Tags: sorting

```
> echo "fdp.txtUNE/ser/redaeR/daerorca/bil/rsu\nf.dpu" | sort -s 
fdp.txtUNE/ser/redaeR/daerorca/bil/rsu 
f.dpu
```

Since "." is not a field separating character by default, the first 3 
characters appear to say:

- f <= f (that's fine)
- d <= . (in ASCII, "." < "d", but I'm OK with sort deciding letters 
  come before punctuation)
- p <= d (this is problematic)

Even worse, if I remove one letter from the second string, the results 
are reversed:

```
> echo "fdp.txtUNE/ser/redaeR/daerorca/bil/rsu\nf.dp" | sort -s 
f.dp 
fdp.txtUNE/ser/redaeR/daerorca/bil/rsu
```

What hideousness is going on here and how do I stop it? I thought "-s" 
would suffice, but apparently not.

From what I can tell, 'sort' thinks "f.dpu" > "fdp.t" because "u" > "t". However, that comparison should never be made, since characters before it already differ.

As a note, I get the same results without the "-s".

EDIT: setting environment variable LC_ALL to "C" fixes this, but it still bugs me that leaving LC_ALL (locale) blank yields inconsistent results (different is OK, inconsitent is bad).

Comment: Well, I'm echoing directly from the terminal, so I think not.

Comment: Duplicate of [sort not sorting as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909404/sort-not-sorting-as-expected-space-and-locale). From the GNU FAQ: "[case is folded and punctuation is ignored](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/faq/)"; spaces and punctuation are used only as tie-breakers. "fdptxtU" comes before "fdpu".

Comment: @RaymondChen You're right. I had my LANG environment variable set to "en_US.iso88591", which apparently has the same effect as the en_US.UTF-8 mentioned in the FAQ. I thought "-s" would stop the "tiebreaker" effect, but apparently not. Please write up your answer and I will approve it. It's frustrating sort doesn't have an "--ignore-local" option (although setting environment variable LC_ALL to C works), and that files sorted on one machine are unsorted on another.

Comment: OK, it turns out "sort -d" (dictionary order) might be consistent across machines.

Comment: It is not consistent between a US-English machine and a Swedish machine. If you want consistency, you have to make sure everybody is using the same locale. Feel free to write up your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

First, I had to turn on expanded echo:

```
$ shopt -s xpg_echo
```

Now, I'll run what you gave:

```
BASH 3.2:$ echo "fdp.txtUNE/ser/redaeR/daerorca/bil/rsu\nf.dpu" | sort -s
f.dpu
fdp.txtUNE/ser/redaeR/daerorca/bil/rsu
```

This is the correct sorted order the `.` is sorted before `d`, so `f.dpu` should come first.

I'm not getting your results. It could be because I'm on Mac OS X and not Linux. However, the `-s` option on both says "stabilize sort by disabling last-resort comparison". Are they any other shell options you have set that might be causing these issues?

Here's my shopt settings:

```
$ shopt
cdable_vars     off
cdspell         off
checkhash       off
checkwinsize    on
cmdhist         on
compat31        off
dotglob         off
execfail        off
expand_aliases  on
extdebug        off
extglob         on
extquote        on
failglob        off
force_fignore   on
gnu_errfmt      off
histappend      off
histreedit      off
histverify      off
hostcomplete    on
huponexit       off
interactive_comments    on
lithist         on
login_shell     off
mailwarn        off
no_empty_cmd_completion off
nocaseglob      off
nocasematch     off
nullglob        off
progcomp        on
promptvars      on
restricted_shell    off
shift_verbose   off
sourcepath      on
xpg_echo        on
```

The three differences from the default I have are `exglob`, `lithist`, and `xpg_echo` which I just set in order to get this to work.

Can you think of anything else that could be going on?