# Linux sort treats spaces differently depending on locale

Tags: linux, sorting

This question is a variation of "[sort not sorting as expected (space and locale)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909404/sort-not-sorting-as-expected-space-and-locale)" but there is a point so please bear with me.

For the following input (these are places in Norway):

```
$ more test_data
SANDE
SANDEFJORD
SANDE I VESTFOLD
ØSTFOLD
```

I can sort using a UTF8 locale:

```
$ LANG=en_US.UTF-8 sort test_data
ØSTFOLD
SANDE
SANDEFJORD
SANDE I VESTFOLD
```

This sort is good because it puts the Ø before the S, which is correct, as specified by UTF8. It is NOT good because it doesn't sort "SANDEFJORD" after "SANDE I VESTFOLD", which is what you might expect as a user.

I can also sort using the C locale:

```
$ LANG=C sort test_data
SANDE
SANDE I VESTFOLD
SANDEFJORD
ØSTFOLD
```

This is good because it treats the spaces as a user might expect. But it puts the Ø after the S, which is not good from an international perspective.

I know WHY this is happening - the two locales treat spaces differently, and the C locale is just sorting on byte values so it doesn't understand the non-ANSI text as anything other than bytes. I've read the entry in the [Coreutils FAQ](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/faq/#Sort-does-not-sort-in-normal-order_0021).

The question is: Can sort be used in such a way that it understands UTF-8 but does't ignore spaces? Is this possible without specifying a completely new locale? Is it even possible **by** specifying a completely new locale? I'm struggling to find any resources on this.

Comment: If you write your own compare function, you could use the UTF-8 mechanism for comparing individual characters but not implement the special case for spaces. However, "what a user expects" *does* depend on the location, so while this might not be what you would expect it is what a native speaker would expect (assuming the Unicode people got it right, and I have to assume they did).

Comment: Wait a minute, are you sure ø is before s in the norwegian alphabet? That should be vice versa as ø, som jag har kännt det, has always been in the end with æ + å in standard norwegian alphabet. From this point of view I think sort works exactly as it should be ie. it puts ø after s and not vice versa.

Comment: You're right - Ø does go at the end of the alphabet, along with Æ and Å. Some languages treat 'modified' letters (whatever you want that to mean) as equivalent, others as separate letters. I had Norwegian in the wrong group. So actually to en_US.utf8 locale is getting it wrong. But the no_NO.utf8 locale gets it right, as you would expect.